# Different page templates not showing content in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, templates

We are using Qode's Bridge theme in Wordpress. I have just moved a dev site to the live site and on the Full Width page template it shows no text on the live site but it does on the dev site. On the live site the default template does show content.

For example the Testimonials page (http://unitedconstruction.com/culture/testimonials/) uses a Full Width template and doesn't show the content under the title bar (it is there if you view the code). But the Culture page does show the content (http://unitedconstruction.com/culture/). The only difference between them is that this one uses the default template.

You can also see what I mean about the live site and the dev site on the two home pages.
Live Site (broken): http://unitedconstruction.com/
Dev Site (working): http://ucdev.inventivewebdesign.com/

I have checked all the settings that Qode offers and gone through the CSS and HTML but have not been able to find anything that would cause this.

We'd like the pages to show the content that is coded there. Could anyone please take a look and see if they can catch what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have edited a little bit CSS, because CSS causing issue right now.

If you go to Developer tools, you will see the z-index overlapping on content.

[image]

Now the solution is you have install custom CSS plugin, whatever you love to use. 
Just paste this CSS and you are good to go!

```
 .container, .content, .full_width {
        z-index: unset !important;
        position: relative;
    }
```

This will fix the z-index. And you content will be viewable then.